# Unable to click item in list view in android

Tags: android, list, onitemclicklistener

I am unable to click item on my list in android here is my code:

```
list=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        list.setOnItemClickListener(this);

        TaskListAdapter obj = new TaskListAdapter(this.getApplicationContext()
                ,R.layout.row, tl);
        list.setAdapter(obj);
        //list.setItemsCanFocus(true);
        list.setClickable(true);
```

Here is the list adapter

```
LayoutInflater loi = LayoutInflater.from(con);          
        View v = loi.inflate(rid, parent, false);   
        TextView tv1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txt1);
        TextView tv2 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txt2);
        //iv.setBackgroundResource(arrow);
        v.setClickable(true);
        v.setFocusable(true);
        final int pos = position;

        tv1.setText(objs.get(position).GuestName);
        tv2.setText(objs.get(position).TaskID);

        return v;
```

here is my click item handler

```
@Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
//      Intent in = new Intent();
//      in.putExtra("GuestID", tl.get(arg2).GuestID);
//      in.putExtra("ReservationID", tl.get(arg2).ReservationID);
//      in.putExtra("CustomerID", custId);
//      in.putExtra("Token", token);
        getGuestDetails(tl.get(arg2).GuestID, tl.get(arg2).ReservationID);

    }
```

here is the xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:background="#f1eff0">


    <TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:stretchColumns="1" android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/toptab" android:id="@+id/tb1">

        <TableRow>

            <Button android:id="@+id/btnback" android:background="@color/hover_bckbtn"
                android:text="Back" android:textColor="#ffffff" android:textSize="14sp"
                android:textStyle="normal" android:typeface="normal"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" />


            <TextView android:id="@+id/tvnormalcallreg" android:text="List View"
                android:textColor="#ffffff" android:textSize="18sp"
                android:layout_gravity="center" android:textStyle="normal"
                android:typeface="normal" />

            <Button android:id="@+id/btnregister" android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:background="@color/hover_button" android:text="Register"
                android:textSize="14sp" android:textStyle="normal" android:typeface="normal"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

    <ListView android:id="@+id/list" 
    android:scrollbars="none"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tb1"  
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
        android:fadingEdge="none"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"/>

    <TableLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:id="@+id/bottom">

        <TableRow android:background="@drawable/toptab"
            android:gravity="center">

            <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="@drawable/logobottom" />
        </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>



</RelativeLayout>
```

Please help me I am new in android??

Comment: Did you implement method `isEnabled(int position)` in adapter?

Comment: Method of adapter. Just return `true` for items that should be clickable and `false` for all others.

Comment: is your listview inside some scrollview??

Comment: no,added the xml as well

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#setOnItemClickListener(android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener)    here you can see that instead of passing context in onItemClickListener you need to pass a onitemclicklistener

Answer (score 1):

Problem Solved

I commented out these lines

```
v.setClickable(true);
v.setFocusable(true);
```

and my code worked

Answer (score 0):

Do you actually have a click listener? I can see you set the click listener to *this*, but you haven't added the code showing the implementation of the click listener.

Comment: implements OnItemClickListener,OnClickListener

Comment: what error are you getting, and are you certain that it is not clicked? (have you tried printing something to LogCat from the listener)

Comment: not getting any error but I am not able to click the item in my list

Comment: I am printing an statement and also I am debugging and not getting my control their in listner????